# How to load jpg textures using three.js MTL loader?

Tags: three.js

This is my code:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( '3dAssets/structure1/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'Structure_Combined.mtl', function( materials ) {
    materials.preload();
    mtl = materials;
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( '3dAssets/structure1/' );
    objLoader.load( 'Structure_Combined.obj', function ( object ) {
        object.position.y = - 13;
        scene.add( object );
    });
});
```

The following is my .mtl file:

```
newmtl aiStandard2SG
illum 4
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
map_Kd Suela_Master_A.jpg

newmtl aiStandard3SG
illum 4
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
map_Kd Suela_A2.jpg
```

Every answer regarding this topic uses .dds texture maps, however at the time of loading, it doesn't seem to even attempt to load jpg files, .dds files add a handler with the following code to allow the loading: 
    THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
Maybe there's a similar thing for jpg?